# How to serialize a C# class into Javascript on Response?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, webforms

I have a class like this :

```
public class Person
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {

    }
}
```

on server side, I populate some instance of this class, and I add them into an `IEnumerable<Person>`.
Well, now, on client side, I'd like to receive this collection as javascript (json?), as happens with web services and serialization. (`[Serializable()]`)

How can I do it in a normal response, after a webform request in .NET 3.5?

Comment: [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) should be able to do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to serialize an object to JSON.

Or, even better, create a [WebService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webservice.aspx) marked with [ScriptService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx).

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class SimpleWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetServerTime() 
    {
        string serverTime =
            String.Format("The current time is {0}.", DateTime.Now);

        return serverTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that JS Serializer... I get `System.ArgumentException: RecursionLimit exceeded.`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/):

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person() { Address = "5 Foo Street", Name = "Fed", Surname = "Fish" });
persons.Add(new Person() { Address = "10 Bar Road", Name = "Joe", Surname = "Smith" });

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons);
```

Comment: And on server side? How can I mange "output"? Can you give to me an example?

Comment: This is on the server side - output is just a string you can write to the `Response`

Comment: Sorry! I meant on client side.. a typo :)

Comment: On the client side if you have jquery you can just use `getJSON()`, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/